# The use of the word "hinder" in context

Tags: word-choice

Suppose there are two persons in a room and one person wants to take a selfie of themselves, but cannot because the other one will be in the photo. So will it be to correct and natural to use *hinder* in the following sentence?

> The man is hindering her in taking the selfie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the preposition to use with "hinder" is *from*.

> The man was hindering her **from** taking a selfie, by always standing in the background.

"Hinder" also usually implies some kind of active role in preventing something, as if the man was *deliberately* stopping her from taking a photo. However, this is not always the case, especially with inanimate objects:

> The fallen tree **hindered** them from driving any farther up the narrow road.

That being said, using "hinder" is kind of any overly florid way to express a simple concept:

> She couldn't take a selfie because that man was always **in the way**.

Answer (score 0):

Someone might wrongly believe that he  took action to prevent the photo if you expressed it in that way. If you wanted to prevent that inference, you could say something like this:

> That he  would appear in her selfie hindered | kept her from taking it.

or

> She did not take a selfie because she felt hindered by him appearing in it.